# Result of `quote do: unquote({:a, :b, :c})`

Tags: elixir

I'm new to `quote` and `unquote` in Elixir and I'm trying to understand why we get `{:a, :b, :c}` when using

```
value = {:a, :b, :c}
quote do: unquote({:a, :b, :c})
#=> result will be {:a, :b, :c}
```

and why it's not `{:{}, [], [:a, :b, :c]}` as I would expect? Could somebody please explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Kernel.SpecialForms.quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#quote/2) converts the argument to its [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

[`Kernel.SpecialForms.unquote/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote/1) allows to use values from the outside of the `quote` block inside quote. The compiler expects quoted expressions / abstract syntax tree as an input. It gets the valid AST as an argument and expands this AST in the current context. That said, `unquote/1` is kinda counterpart of `quote/2`, that’s why `quote(do: unquote(foo))` is basically *noop*, returning `foo`.

One might avoid the necessity to call `unquote` anywhere inside quoted expression by passing the binding to `bind_quoted:` keyword parameter in a call to `quote` like this

```
foo = {:a, :b, :c}
quote bind_quoted: [foo: foo] do
  elem(foo, 1)
end
```

If you want to see the AST of the arbitrary piece of code, use `quote/2`.

---

I’d strongly suggest you read the [official documentation on quoting](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html).

Answer (score 0):

The result you are expecting is for the expression:

```
quote do: {:a, :b, :c}
```

`unquote` does the 'inverse transform' of `quote`, so

```
quote do: unquote(x)
```

is just x.

This is used for code like this:

```
number = 1
quote do: 1 + unquote(number)
```

(if you don't unquote it here, then literally 'number' gets substituted).

This lets you define partially constant data, something like a template.